# Proper way of dealing with lists in parameters of raw query in EF core with postgresql

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

What is the right way of dealing with list of items which I need to include in WHERE IN query? In my use case, I need to use list of DateTimes. My current solution is pretty awful because I embedded data in query and I would prefer to use query parameters.

```
            var n = String.Join(",", dates.Select(item => $"'{item.ToString()}'::timestamp"));
            var q = $@"
SELECT c.date AS date, a.id AS user_id, a.user_name AS user_name, a.email AS user_email, COALESCE(sum(te.amount), 0) AS summary
FROM asp_net_users a
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
                     FROM calendar
                     WHERE date IN({n})
) c
         LEFT JOIN time_entries te on a.id = te.user_id AND c.date = te.date
WHERE a.department_guid = '95b7538d-3830-48d7-ba06-ad7c51a57191'
GROUP BY c.date, a.id
HAVING COALESCE(sum(te.amount), 0) > 480
ORDER BY c.date
";
```

When I try to use dates as array in query parameter I receive following error:

```
operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = timestamp[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be over-engineering if array input is used rarely but I think worth trying. You can try a custom db parameter and extension to overcome your problem

First things first. You need a custom DbParameter type

```cs
public class SqlListParameter : DbParameter
{
    private string _internalName;
    protected string InternalName
    {
        get => _internalName;
        set => _internalName = NormalizeParameterName(value);
    }

    public override DbType DbType { get; set; }
    public override ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public override bool IsNullable { get; set; }

    public override string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    public override object Value { get; set; }
    public override bool SourceColumnNullMapping { get; set; }
    public override int Size { get; set; }

    public override string ParameterName
    {
        get => InternalName;
        set => InternalName = value;
    }

    public override void ResetDbType()
    {

    }

    public SqlListParameter(string parameterName)
    {
        InternalName = parameterName;
    }

    internal static string NormalizeParameterName(string parameterName)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterName) || parameterName.First() == '@'
            ? parameterName
            : "@" + parameterName;
    }
}
```

And extend the `Database.SqlQuery` to be able to use our custom DbParameter

```cs
public static class SqlQueryExtensions
{
    public static DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> ExtendedSqlQuery<TElement>(this Database db, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var listParameters = parameters.Where(n => n.GetType() == typeof(SqlListParameter)).ToArray();

        sql = listParameters.Aggregate(sql, (dbSql, parameter) => ApplyList(dbSql, parameter as SqlListParameter));

        parameters = parameters.Where(n => n.GetType() != typeof(SqlListParameter)).ToArray();

        return db.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, parameters);
    }

    private static string ApplyList(string sql, SqlListParameter parameter)
    {
        var list = parameter.Value as IEnumerable<int>;

        if (list == null)
            throw new SqlListException("SqlListParameter value should has could be casted to IEnumerable<int>");

        var joinedListItems = string.Join(",", list);

        return sql.Replace(parameter.ParameterName, joinedListItems);
    }
}
```

Finally you can use it like below

```cs
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
       var parameters = new object[]
    {
        new SqlListParameter("@identsList") { Value = new [] { 1, 2 }}, 
        new SqlParameter("@nameParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "Test1"}, 
    };

    var isFoundEntry = context.Database.ExtendedSqlQuery<TestEntity>("select * from TestEntities where Id in (@identsList) and name=@nameParam", parameters).Any();
}
```

Hope it helps.